# What do the headers in the PowerShell ps output mean?

Tags: command-line, powershell

If I type `ps` in PowerShell, I obtain something like:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName          
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------          
     45       2      524       1812    12             376 AEstSrv              
     40       2      624       2028    13             484 agrsmsvc             
    137       5     1540       4760    50            1568 atieclxx             
    123       4      996       3196    27             920 atiesrxx             
    122       5    15584      14688    46            4816 audiodg              
    138       5     1536       4808    55            6132 audiosrv
```

Can someone give me the definitions of the various headers here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you type

```
get-help get-process -full
```

You will get an explanation of these terms.  Here it is:

> The default display of a process is a
>   table that includes the following
>   columns:
>
> -- Handles: The number of handles that the process has opened.
>
> -- NPM(K): The amount of non-paged memory that the process is using, in
>   kilobytes.
>
> -- PM(K): The amount of pageable memory that the process is using, in
>   kilobytes.
>
> -- WS(K): The size of the working set of the process, in kilobytes. The
>   working set consists of the pages of
>   memory that were recently referenced
>   by the process.
>
> -- VM(M): The amount of virtual memory that the process is using, in
>   megabytes. Virtual memory includes
>   storage  in the paging files on disk.
>
> -- CPU(s): The amount of processor time that the process has used on all
>   processors, in seconds.
>
> -- ID: The process ID (PID) of the process.
>
> -- ProcessName: The name of the process.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I asked, and the question I didn't ask.